# Arabic in Phonegap for Windowsphone7?

Tags: cordova

I'm coding my HTML page to convert it to .xap using Phonegap.
My app contains some Arabic and Persian description in about page.
My app keeps crashing when I'm testing it.
What should I do?
thanks for helping

Comment: Can't you show any code or the reason the phone is saying it's crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Arabic should run well under Cordova/PhoneGap on WP7. To make sure the problem is really related to Arabic you can try to replace/remove this text and try to run the app. This will give you an idea if this is really related to Arabic or not.

If the application is crashed/force closed this mean there is something wrong with the application itself (native part, missing/wrong file references, etc), not with your html/js files.

If you see blank white screen instead of the html app then the problem with the html/js files.

The general recommendation is to try the latest Cordova/Phonegap for WP7 
http://phonegap.com/download

Comment: I removed Arabic.The app installed and opened.I think it's because Internet explorer doesn't support Arabic.

Comment: Seems you are right http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2283917. But some ppl were able to get it working by 'correcting UTF8 characters' http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=22420871

Comment: Could you please post a link to an example page?

Comment: I can add links to Arabic sites and the app runs correctly but  the Arabic texts are not shown correctly